# How do I merge lists in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have 2 lists, for example:
[1, 2, 3] and [4, 5, 6]
How do I merge them into 1 new list?:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
not
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

Comment: `l1 + l2`. You can simply add them.

Comment: Python makes this ridiculously easy: `[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6]` that's it.

Comment: They look like plain Python lists, not [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html).

Comment: @PM2Ring That's probably what he meant. I've seen quite a few people who don't understand the difference between list and arrays in Python. They use the two terms synonymously.

Comment: @ChristianDean Indeed, and I'm doing my small part to reverse that trend. ;) It may seem a little pedantic, but when there are two built-in array-like types (lists and tuples), the arrays of the `array` module I linked above, plus Numpy arrays, I think it's important to give these things their correct names.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists Tutorial about list

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`+` operator can be used to merge two lists.

```
data1 = [1, 2, 3]
data2 = [4, 5, 6]

data = data1 + data2

print(data)

# output : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Lists can be merged like this in python.

Building on the same idea, if you want to join multiple lists or a list of lists to a single list, you can still use "+" but inside a reduce method like this,

```
from functools import reduce 

l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
l3 = [7, 8, 9]
l4 = [10, 11, 12]

l = [l1, l2, l3, l4]

data = reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, l)
print(data)

# output : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 8):

By using the `+`  operator, like this:

```
>>> [1, 2] + [3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```